# Equivalent of Rs which in pandas

Tags: pandas

How do I get the column of the min in the example below, not the actual number?

In R I would do:

```
which(min(abs(_quantiles - mean(_quantiles))))
```

In pandas I tried (did not work):

```
_quantiles.which(min(abs(_quantiles - mean(_quantiles))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way, call `np.min` on the df as a np array, use this to create a boolean mask and drop the columns that don't have at least a single non `NaN` value:

```
In [2]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(5), 'b':np.random.randn(5)})
df

Out[2]:
          a         b
0 -0.860548 -2.427571
1  0.136942  1.020901
2 -1.262078 -1.122940
3 -1.290127 -1.031050
4  1.227465  1.027870

In [15]:
df[df==np.min(df.values)].dropna(axis=1, thresh=1).columns

Out[15]:
Index(['b'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 0):

`idxmin` and `idxmax` exist, but no general `which` as far as I can see.

```
_quantiles.idxmin(abs(_quantiles - mean(_quantiles)))
```

Comment: I do not think this does what I thought it does... Anyone confirm?